# Probability of eight 500 year events?

Tags: probability

[This article](http://www.planetizen.com/node/88047/climate-change-eight-500-year-storms-may-2014) states that there have been eight 500 years storms since May of 2015.  Given that it states that the probability of the such an event is 0.2 percent in any given year, what is the probability of getting 8 such events in the time period between then and now - consider that to be 15 months exactly.

It is the time factor that has me unable to figure this out myself.  Also, I am only interested in the mathematics of the probability calculation.  I know there are other groups where the merits of that article can be discussed.  Please let's just keep this to the math!

Comment: There is a  saying in finance that the 100 year event happens every 2 or 3 years.  There are couple of reasons for this.  The "hundred year event" is determined by looking at data over a short horizon and assuming that uncertainty is normally distributed (which it isn't).  Not appreciating the increase in correlation at the tails. And looking at so many disparate data, and labeling the 100 year event for each one.

Comment: @DougM I think the OP is looking for a simple statistical formulation, which ignores the correlation. That would be given by a Poisson distribution, right?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel yes, you would be correct.

Comment: "Given that it states that the probability of the such an event is 0.2 percent in any given year"  This seems ambiguous.  Does this mean in a given year it is .2 percent this will occur anywhere in the world at any time in the year.  Or that given a specific storm lasting one week the probability is .2/52 percent it will be that bad.  Or that given an area has on average 4 storms a year that any one of them has a .05 percent chance of being that bad  Those are 3 very different statements.

Comment: do you know the standard deviation or the variance of the reference datas ? The SD is known to have a large value on 500 y. Ideally, if you find in the datas 7 years with 8 storms, you may understand that the probability you search is about 7/500. Note if we are living a big change, old datas may help but are not relevant to evaluate this precise probability

Comment: For what I am/was interested in, I was assuming that, over a 500 year sample size, the event were independent.  Also, the events merely have the same probability, I do not believe that they are the same (say rain) event.  Like a '1' have a 1 in 6 chance of being rolled on a die, is the same as say a poor QB that, on average, throws an interception once every six passes.  The events are uncorrelated, but NOAA certifies them as 1 every 500 year events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a one-year window we have a mean of $\frac1{500}$ 500-year storms occurring. In a 15-month ($\frac54$ year) window we would thus expect a mean of $\frac1{500}\times\frac54=\frac1{400}$ storms.

Now *assuming the independence of storms*, we will model them by the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). This distribution has one parameter, the mean, which is $\lambda=\frac1{400}$ here. Given a window and a mean, the probability that *k* events occur in the window is
$$\frac{\lambda^ke^{-\lambda}}{k!}$$
Substituting the values in, we get a probability of $3.775\times10^{-26}$ that eight 500-year storms happen in 15 months.

Of course, given the butterfly effect and the extent of human impact on the environment, the above calculation is not a realistic one.

Comment: Thank you - I really like this.  I was not thinking this through very well and was also only considering a uniform distribution (which doesn't make much sense to me now)